# Is this level of wear okay on a new chainring

Tags: road-bike, shimano, maintenance, chainring

Very recently I bought my first new bike! I only did 750km on it so far. However the the chain rings are showing some level of wear, see picture. The teeth used to be all black, now you can see bits of silver on them. I just want to care for the bike with everything I can do. So let me know if this is because of misuse somehow. [image: before the teeth were all black, now you can see bits of silver.]

Comment: Looks fairly normal to me.

Comment: The paint is part of the coating and one of the first things to peel off. Looks normal to me, even the Mona Lisa is falling apart.

Comment: It’s just paint. Juhist will soon arrive and explain how these chainrings can last 10 thousand kilometers, so don’t worry.

Comment: This only begs the question, why did they paint the chainring in the first place? They must have known that the paint would peel off pretty quickly, and that the chainring would look much worse from it than if it had not been painted at all. Weird world.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica - probably easier to pain the whole thing than to have a tricky and messy mask to do the body and not the teeth.

Comment: @MaplePanda: No, Juhist will tell you that only steel chainrings are true chainrings. Aluminium is going to fail after a single Sunday afternoon ride, or something like that ;)

Comment: @awjlogan Obviously. My point was that I don't see any point in painting it at all. If it's aluminum, it's fine. If it's steel, just burn it black so it looks good in the showroom and does not accumulate rust too quickly. Or simply go for stainless steel, and it'll look as good as if it were aluminum. Neither method involves any paint that will chip off in the way shown in the OP's picture.

Comment: Side-thought .... are you spending significant time in the bigger rear cogs while on the big chainring, perhaps while climbing?  If so, it might help to use the inner chainring some more when the road pitches up.   This *might*  be a sign of cross chaining.

Comment: @MaplePanda: But only of the wheels have 48 spokes each! Sarcasm aside, the chain might be running a bit dry.

Comment: @Criggie I think I actually tend to do this on climbs. Interesting, should indeed use the small ring more. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I feel better about this reading your comments.

Comment: @Carel I clean and lube the chain once every 10 days almost. I don’t think this is the issue. But maybe dirt in the chain?

Comment: @Carel On a second thought, I don't think this is the reason, since I get this chipping off on both sides of the teeth.

Answer (score 1):

Chainrings are special wear items in that they can be used even if severely visibly worn. It is very typical of used chainrings to show wear in the points that transmit forces, being a visibly different location than the points that don't transmit forces.

In some chainrings, it is possible to "rotate" the chainring on the crankset to even out the wear. However, your chainring seems to have these unfortunately new trendy non-even bolt patterns so "rotation" is impossible and you can't prolong the wear life of the chainring past what it experiences at the fixed orientation.

I remember seeing a picture of a chainring that was used either 300 000 miles or 300 000 km (don't remember which). It was by Jobst Brandt, the author of The Bicycle Wheel. That chainring was rotated multiple times in its wear life to even out wear. Unfortunately, I didn't store that chainring picture and it's gone from the 'net now. The 300 Kkm / Kmile chainring had practically no teeth left yet it still worked perfectly.

There's a long way to go until your chainring fails.

Comment: That’s reassuring, thanks!